# Size bound on Büchi automaton for complement

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, regular-language, nondeterminism, omega-language

For a given Büchi automaton $\mathcal A = (A, Q, \delta, q_0, F)$ we define a congruence on $A^{\ast}$ by
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
 u \sim_{\mathcal A} v & :\Leftrightarrow & \mbox{for all }s,s' \in Q \mbox{ we have a path} \\
& & \mbox{from $s$ to $s'$ labeled by $v$ iff we have} \\
& & \mbox{such a path labeled by $w$ and} \\
& & \mbox{we have such a path which passes through a state from $F$} \\
& & \mbox{labeled by $v$ iff we have such a path labeled by $w$}. 
\end{array}
$$
for $u, v \in A^{\ast}$. Now setting 
$W_{ss'} := \{ w \in A^{\ast} \mid \mbox{there is a path labeled $w$ from $s$ to $s'$}\}$ and $W_{ss'}^{F} := \{ w \in A^{\ast} \mid \mbox{there is a path labeled $w$ from $s$ to $s'$ going through a state in $F$}\}$ we have
$$
 [w]_{\sim_{\mathcal A}} = \bigcap_{\substack{s,s'\in Q \\ w \in W_{ss'}}} W_{ss'} \cap \bigcap_{\substack{s,s' \in Q \\ w \in A^{\ast} \setminus W_{ss'}}} A^{\ast}\setminus W_{ss'}
 \bigcap_{\substack{s,s'\in Q \\ w \in W_{ss'}^F}} W_{ss'}^F \cap \bigcap_{\substack{s,s' \in Q \\ w \in A^{\ast} \setminus W_{ss'}^F}} A^{\ast}\setminus W_{ss'}^F.
$$ 
This equivalence is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementation_of_B%C3%BCchi_automaton) and also in the the chapter *Automata on infinite objects* by Wolfgang Thomas in the Handbook of Theoretical Computer Science, Volume II. In this book it is said

> Let us consider the complexity of the complementation process and the equivalence test. Given a Büchi automaton with $n$ states, there are $n^2$ different pairs $(s,s')$ and hence $O(2^{2n^2})$ different $\sim_{\mathcal A}$-classes. This leads to size bound of $O(2^{4n^2})$ states for the complement automaton.

As in the above formula, for each set $W_{ss'}$ (and $W_{ss'}^F$) we can decide wether it occurs in the intersection (and hence determines if one complement $A^{\ast}\setminus W_{ss'}$ and $A^{\ast} \setminus W_{ss'}^F$ occurs) we have $2^{n^2}\cdot 2^{n^2}$ options (different then $|Q^{2^{2Q}}|$ which would be given by the identification of the classes with functions $f : Q \to 2^Q \times 2^Q$ in the wikipedia article).

> But why does this lead to a size bound of $O(2^{4n^2})$ for the complement automaton?

I do not see how to get a complement automaton such that this size bound could be easily seen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have the bound $2^{2n^2}$ on the number of classes, you can note that each state in the complement automaton corresponds to an $\omega$-regular language of the form $L_{f}L_{g}^\omega$, with $L_f$ and $L_g$ being functions from $Q$ to $2^Q\times 2^Q$.

Each such language is determined by $L_f$ and $L_g$, and there are $2^{2n^2}$ options for these functions, so you get a total of $(2^{2n^2})^2=2^{4n^2}$ options.

UPDATE FOLLOWING COMMENT:
The correspondence of the number $2^{4n^2}$ to the states of the constructed automaton is not exact. Observe that for every language $L_f$, we can construct a nondeterministic NFA $A_f$ (as is done in Theorem 1 in the Wikipedia link you posted). Moreover, the size of $A_f$ is polynomial in the size of the original NBW $A$. Thus, the size of an NBW for $L_fL_g^\omega$ is polynomial. You then take a union of $2^{4n^2}$ such automata, and obtain the complement NBW, so the size of the complement NBW is:
$$2^{4n^2}\cdot poly(n)=2^{4n^2 +\log poly(n)}=2^{O(4n^2)}$$
So it's a little less tight than $O(2^{4n^2})$, but it's still only singly exponential (perhaps there is a tighter analysis, but I'm not aware of one).

Comment: Looking at the proof I see that the complement is a finite union of sets of the form $L_f L_g^{\omega}$, by why is there a correspondence between those sets and the states of the Büchi automaton for the complement (i.e. what you are saying in your second paragraph)? PS: This was a typo in the definition, I meant $[w]_{\sim_{\mathcal A}}$.

Comment: I updated my answer.